# Check denominator

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I would like to calculate percents and do:

```
double n = ...;
double total = ...;
double percents = (total == 0) ? 0 : (n/ total) * 100;
```

R# warns me "Fix floating number compare". And hints of using EPSILON. I clearly understand why this warning is showed in general. But in this case the only I want, is to avoid throwing exception. So I "state" on fixed 0.

Is it right assumption or there are some hidden flaw and I should use some epsilon anyway?

Comment: There are finite values of `n` and `total` which result in an infinite result, even with you `0` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with floating-point dividing by 0.0.

You only get DivideByZeroExceptions for integer division.

The problem you get though is that 1.0/0.0 results in Infinity.

If this is for displaying, just use `string.Format`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the use of Epsilon here. You're check for totals equality of 0 is solely for the purpose of preventing DivideByZeroExceptions. Of course there are the gotcha's of rounding but those are not related to the warning and apply only to the n/total expression